# Cannot import Map.Entry

Tags: java, hashmap

I have problems with import Map.Entry. Even though I have import import java.util.Map.Entry - there is an error :  "The import java.util.Map.Entry cannot be resolved". And  entrySet() method doesnot work. what is the problem? (I use jre8)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import java.util.Set;

import org.biojava3.core.sequence.ProteinSequence;
import org.biojava3.core.sequence.io.FastaReaderHelper;




public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    LinkedHashMap<String, ProteinSequence> a = FastaReaderHelper.readFastaProteinSequence(new File("A2RTH4.fasta"));

    for (Map.Entry<String, ProteinSequence> entry : a.entrySet(); //entrySet A map entry (key-value pair). 
    {
        System.out.println( entry.getValue().getOriginalHeader() + "=" + entry.getValue().getSequenceAsString() );
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: "And entrySet() method does not work" - in what way? Please be more precise. Also, please provide a short but complete example demonstrating the problem. It works fine for me...

Comment: Tried to reproduce, but `import java.util.Map.Entry` lets me declare an instance of `Entry` without problems. Could you show us some code?

Comment: Code please. No code no help.

Comment: I add code so u can look at it

Comment: Just copied your code and made a few mocks for ProteinSequence etc. The only error I got is that there is a ")" missing in your `for` loop. The semicolon (";") should be a ")". Does the problem remain when you do that?

Comment: Yes still it remains, do u thing it might be a problem with eclipse installation or JRE system library?

Comment: Possible. Sometimes it helps to use "Clean Project".

Comment: Is it say something more ?Multiple markers at this line
 - The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
  required .class files

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? Then it’s [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26105217/2711488)

Answer (score 5):

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : someMap.entrySet())
```

works with `import java.util.Map` import alone.

Answer (score 0):

`import java.util.Map` is enough

Try this code, should be work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
LinkedHashMap<String, ProteinSequence> a = FastaReaderHelper.readFastaProteinSequence(new File("A2RTH4.fasta"));
Set entrySet = a.entrySet();
Iterator it = entrySet.iterator();
// Iterate through LinkedHashMap entries
System.out.println("LinkedHashMap entries : ");
while(it.hasNext())
  System.out.println(it.next());
  }
}
```

Instead of foreach, try an Iterator to iterate over a LinkedHashMap data structure.

Comment: even if i have import java.util.Map i have problem with my code line

for (Map.Entry<String, ProteinSequence> entry : a.entrySet();


eclipse says : reference to the  missing element 'Map.Entry'

Comment: Maybe you have to set Eclipse correctly, but posting code will be the better solution for help.

Comment: There is a syntax error, close parenthesis out the for cycle.

Comment: thats true, but it s not the main problem. still it s wrong something with the reference to Map.Entry

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ProteinSequence> entry : a.entrySet();
```

should be

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ProteinSequence> entry : a.entrySet())
```

(closing parenthesis instead of semicolon).