# Some classes not being found when using JDK 8?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

I am using Eclipse in Ubuntu Linux.

For some reason some classes are simply not found, for example Comparator or Arrays.

I have noticed something very strange. When I view the library in Eclipse I can see that most .class files allow you to click on them and it displays a 'C' icon - for example 'Comparators' in the screenshot below. Comparator does not allow this dropdown - could this be part of the problem? The same also goes for Arrays.class and BitSet.class, as you can see.

[image]

Why the hell can I not reference Comparator in the IDE??

Comment: are you able to get comparator class using command prompt

Comment: When you say 'get it' what do you mean. Is that .class file there or can I actually link to the Comparator class?

Comment: i mean are you able to use Comparator class, by running some simple program. Just want to make sure it jdk issue or IDE

Comment: I can compile and run a program using Comparator in the command line.

Comment: Well, you didn’t name the *version* of Eclipse but the problem sounds much like [you have to update your Eclipse version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26105217/2711488). `Comparator` has even both, `static` *and* `default` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that, as @Holger suggested, this was a problem with my version of Eclipse. I was running Eclipse Indigo. Once I updated to Eclipse Luna the strange compilation errors were fixed. I was also able to change the compiler compliance level to 1.8 and make use of JDK 8 constructs such as the Lambda, which I was unable to do in Indigo.