# Unable to resolve Map in Intellij 11 JDK8

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8

intellij 11 problem with Java JDK8 unable to resolve Map and other class like Array

Intellij 11 unable to resolve the some classes including Map, Array etc

I am using jdk1.8.0_25 with intellij 11

intellij 11 problem with Java JDK8 unable to resolve Map [unable to resolve Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2obH.png)

Comment: Of course, a decompiler not updated to support Java 8 features, will stumble across Java 8 features. But I don’t get why you need to decompile classes for which the source code is supplied with the JDK…

Comment: i dont want to decompile these classes intellij 11 Map class is resolvable but compile successfully but i am facing problem in development because of this issue intellij intelligence not working

Comment: In that case, [it’s even easier](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26105217/2711488). Just update IntelliJ to a version which support Java 8.

Comment: Who downvoted this question?  It actually helped me figure out the issue with a colleague who was having this problem.  He had the ancient version of intelliJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade to a compatible version of IntelliJ that supports Java 8. There was support released in [IntelliJ 12](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/whatsnew_121.html).

> **What's New in IntelliJ IDEA 12? And 12.1…**
>
> Java 8
>
> Complete IDE support for the next generation of the Java platform,
>   with code assistance for the new syntax, such as lambda expressions,
>   method references, default methods and type annotations.

And support was improved in [IntelliJ 13](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/whatsnew_13.html)

> **What's New in IntelliJ IDEA 13?**
>
> Java 8
>
> Support for Java 8 has been improved according to the latest [updates](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html).