# Issue with Jtable in jdk8

Tags: java, swing, java-8

On JDK 8

> import javax.swing.JTable

Giving the below error

```
The import javax.swing.JTable cannot be resolved
```

I searching in net but none of the ans working for me..i know its duplicate but ans suggested not working for me

Comment: rebuild your project

Comment: i changed it jdk7 its working fine..

Comment: are you using Eclipse?

Comment: ofcourse yes gelilio

Comment: Check the build path and that the JDK8 system library is in it in the libraries tab.

Comment: Go to project properties, "Java Build Path", and "Add Library" -> "JRE system library" and make sure to select java 1.8. If it does not exist, press "Installed JREs" and set up the 1.8 library

Comment: [No chance without updating to an Eclipse version with Java 8 support…](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26105217/2711488)