# Getting Error The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jsp, java-8

Getting Below error on Jsp when added below Code..

Code : `Map<Long, String> topMenuMap = new HashMap<Long, String>();`

> Error : The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved.

It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: A general recommendation would be to put your Map in a Controller/Servlet

Comment: [Update your toolchain, JSP engine, libraries, frameworks, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26105217/2711488)…

Answer (score 3):

`import java.util.*` in JSP page `<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>`

Answer (score 0):

here they say to upgrade Tomcat 7 to higher version to be compatible with Java 8.
Minimum version is Tomcat 7.0.54

https://www.howopensource.com/2015/07/unable-to-compile-class-for-jsp-the-type-java-util-mapentry-cannot-be-resolved/